# chrome web store app submit button stopped working

Tags: google-apps-script, chrome-web-store

I have a Chrome Web Store app, written in Google Apps Script, it's been in the store over a year and has been working well - a day or so ago it stopped working. Specifically, the submit button on the first page just doesn't do anything any more (used to move to the next screen). I have over 2,000 users and would appreciate any advise or info on any underlying problems with the Chrome Web Store.

The submit button code is just: `input type="submit" class="button" name="submit"` and the form `method="post"`

The [code](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwF1SzVezK0YVmW2ZoWY1UAjS5KnjL6L4vDLmbyMD9or81WNE0/exec) had not changed for some time and now it has just stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to a change Google made to the default SandboxMode see https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3721
You can get your app working again by adding adding  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.EMULATED) to your code.